# 'half space' in matplotlib labels and legend

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I insert a half space in the text of matplotlib labels or legends, e.g. between numbers and their units? A simple workaround would be to use latex rendering, but is there an other way, e.g. using unicode characters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to use latex rendering. Normal MathText is sufficient. It still has most basic latex capabities, e.g. a small space as `\,` available.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot([1,2], label='$100\,$s')
plt.plot([1,3], label='$100$ s')

plt.legend()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can use the unicode thin space character [`u"\u2009"`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2009/index.htm).

For example, compare the width of the spaces in the legend text here between the "10" and the "km":

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)

ax.plot(np.arange(5), 'r-', label='10 km (normal space)')
ax.plot(5.-np.arange(5), 'b-', label=u"10\u2009km (thin space)")

ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: yes, sorry, I was confused for a second and thought that the special space was behind "km".

Comment: Perhaps more self-documentingly, `u"10\N{thin space}km"` also works.